# Obtener URL de donde estoy situado con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo obtengo la `URL` actual en el sitio web? usando `javascript`.

Lo que quiero es saber si puedo obtener la `url` de un sitio web, pero por ejemplo si estoy en la sección de `/conocenos` quiera obtener `http://sitioWeb/conocenos`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

en `javascript`, se puede obtener el url con: **[location.href](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(location.href);
</script>
```

ó **[window.location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   alert(window.location);
    </script>
```

En resumen puedes utilizar:

**[window.location.href](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)** : obtiene la href (url) de la página actual.

Answer (score 7):

Javascript provee muchos metodos para obtener y cambiar la URL actual, estos metodos usan el objeto Location el cual es una propiedad del objeto Window, tu puedes crear un nuevo objeto Location que tenga el URL actual asi:

```
var LocationActual=window.location;
```

o

```
window.location.href
```

o

```
document.URL;
```

El comportamiento puede depender segun el explorador

Estructura basica de un URL:

```
<protocol>//<hostname>:<port>/<pathname><search><hash>
```

1.- **Protocol** -- Especifica el nombre de protocolo a usar para acceder el recurso de internet (HTTP sin SSL o HTTPS con SSL)

2.- **hostname** -- Especifica el host que posee el recurso, por ejemplo www.stackoverflow. Un servidor provee servicios usando el nombre del host.

3.- **port** -- Un numero de puerto usado para reconocer un proceso especifico al cual se redirecciona un mensaje de una red o internet cuando llega al servidor.

4.- **pathname** -- Provee informacion acerca del recurso especifico dentro del host al cual el cliente web quiere acceer, por ejemplo /index.html

5.- **query** -- Sigue la ruta del componente y provee una cadena de informacion que el recurso puede utilizar para el mismo proposito (ejemplo, parametros de busqueda o datos para procesar)

6.- **hash** -- Identificador de fragmento, incluye el simbolo (#)

Con estas propiedades puedes acceder a todos estos componentes del URL

1. **hash** - Obtiene o establece el identificador de fragmento
2. **host** - Obtiene o establece el hostname y puerto de un URL
3. **hostname** - Obtiene o establece el hostname de un URL
4. **href** - Obtiene o establece el URL entero
5. **pathname** - Obtiene o establece el nombre de ruta de un URL
6. **port** - Obtiene o establece el numero de puerto que el server usa
   para el URL
7. **protocol** - Obtiene o establece el protocolo de una URL
8. **search** - Obtiene o establece la parte de consulta (o query) de un
   URL

Obtenido de: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20746566/3596441

Ver tambien

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location
http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javalocation.html

Answer (score 4):

Si utilizando [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location), lo que es sinónimo de `location.href`

```js
alert(window.location);
```

Nota: este ejemplo no muestra la dirección de stack overflow ya que los stack snippets se hostean en otro dominio.

Answer (score 4):

Sé que ya hay buenas respuestas, pero hay un caso no contemplado que podría ser interesante: ¿qué ocurre si estás dentro de un `iframe`? ¿Esperas la URL del iframe o la que se muestra en el navegador?

Si lo que quieres es la URL indicada en el `src` del `iframe`, el método indicado por otros funcionará:

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Pero si lo que quieres es la URL que se muestra en la barra de dirección del navegador, en ese caso tienes que leer el dato del padre:

```
var url = window.parent.location.href;
```

---

Un método para obtener la URL que aparece en el navegador sería hacer algo como esto:

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ?
                          window.parent.location.href : window.location.href;
```

En ese caso obtendrás la dirección de la página si no está incluída en otra, y si lo está (p.e. a través de un iframe), entonces obtendrás la dirección del padre.